# Converting crc code from C to Java yields unexpected results

Tags: java, c, crc

I am trying to convert CRC C code to Java but I am not getting expected results. Here is what I have so far...

C Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

//Partial code to unit test function

/// zlib's CRC32 polynomial
const uint32_t CrcPolynomial = 0xEDB88320;

/// compute CRC32 (bitwise algorithm)
uint32_t Crc32Bitwise(const void* data, size_t length, uint32_t previousCrc32)
{
    uint32_t crc = ~previousCrc32; // same as previousCrc32 ^ 0xFFFFFFFF
    const uint8_t* current = (const uint8_t*) data;
    while (length-- > 0)
    {
    crc ^= *current++;

    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        crc = (crc >> 1) ^ (-int32_t(crc & 1) & CrcPolynomial);
    }
    }
    return ~crc; // same as crc ^ 0xFFFFFFFF
}

/// compute CRC32 (half-byte algoritm)
uint32_t Crc32HalfByte(const void* data, size_t length, uint32_t previousCrc32 = 0)
{
    uint32_t crc = ~previousCrc32; // same as previousCrc32 ^ 0xFFFFFFFF
    const uint8_t* current = (const uint8_t*) data;

    /// look-up table for half-byte, same as crc32Lookup[0][16*i]
    static const uint32_t Crc32Lookup16[16] =
    {
    0x00000000,0x1DB71064,0x3B6E20C8,0x26D930AC,0x76DC4190,0x6B6B51F4,0x4DB26158,0x5005713C,
    0xEDB88320,0xF00F9344,0xD6D6A3E8,0xCB61B38C,0x9B64C2B0,0x86D3D2D4,0xA00AE278,0xBDBDF21C
    };

    while (length-- > 0)
    {
    crc = Crc32Lookup16[(crc ^  *current      ) & 0x0F] ^ (crc >> 4);
    crc = Crc32Lookup16[(crc ^ (*current >> 4)) & 0x0F] ^ (crc >> 4);
    current++;
    }

    return ~crc; // same as crc ^ 0xFFFFFFFF
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

const char* test_string = "Hello World";
printf("strlen of test_string %ld\n",strlen(test_string));
uint32_t test_crc32_bw = Crc32Bitwise((void*)test_string,strlen(test_string),0);
printf("test_crc32_bw = %d\n",(int32_t) test_crc32_bw);

uint32_t test_crc32_hb = Crc32HalfByte((void*)test_string,strlen(test_string),0);
printf("test_crc32_hb = %d\n",(int32_t) test_crc32_hb);


return 0;
}
```

Result

```
strlen of test_string 11
test_crc32_bw = 1243066710
test_crc32_hb = 1243066710
```

Java Code

```
public class CRC32{


    /// zlib's CRC32 polynomial
private static final long CrcPolynomial = 0xEDB88320L;

public static int LongToInt(long value){
    return (int)(value & 0xFFFFFFFFL);
}

public static long Complement(long value){
    return (value ^ 0xFFFFFFFFL);
}
/// compute CRC32 (bitwise algorithm)
private static long Crc32Bitwise(byte[] data, long length, long previousCrc32)
{
    //long crc = ~previousCrc32; // same as previousCrc32 ^ 0xFFFFFFFF
    //force long to unsigned integer below
    long crc = Complement(previousCrc32);
    for (int i=0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
    crc ^= (data[i]);
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        crc = ((crc) >>> 1) ^ (-(long)((crc) & 1) & CrcPolynomial);
    }
    }
    return Complement(crc); //return crc ^ 0xFFFFFFFF;
}

/// compute CRC32 (bitwise algorithm)
private static long Crc32HalfByte(byte[] data, long length, long previousCrc32)
{    //long crc = ~previousCrc32; // same as previousCrc32 ^ 0xFFFFFFFF
    //force long to unsigned integer below
    long crc = Complement(previousCrc32);
    /// look-up table for half-byte, same as crc32Lookup[0][16*i]
    final long Crc32Lookup16[] = new long[]
    {
    0x00000000,0x1DB71064,0x3B6E20C8,0x26D930AC,0x76DC4190,0x6B6B51F4,0x4DB26158,0x5005713C,
    0xEDB88320,0xF00F9344,0xD6D6A3E8,0xCB61B38C,0x9B64C2B0,0x86D3D2D4,0xA00AE278,0xBDBDF21C
    };

    for (int i=0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
       long temp1 = (crc ^  (data[i])      ) & 0x0F;
       //System.out.format("temp 1 is %d\n", temp1);
       crc = (Crc32Lookup16[LongToInt(temp1)] ^ (crc >>> 4));
       long temp2 = (crc ^ (data[i] >>> 4)) & 0x0F;
       //System.out.format("temp 2 is %d\n", temp2);
       crc = (Crc32Lookup16[LongToInt(temp2)] ^ (crc >>> 4));
    }
    return Complement(crc); //return crc ^ 0xFFFFFFFF;
}


     public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    final String str = "Hello World";
    byte[] test_string = str.getBytes();
    long test_crc32_bw = Crc32Bitwise(test_string,test_string.length,0);
    System.out.format("%d\n",LongToInt(test_crc32_bw));
    long test_crc32_hb = Crc32HalfByte(test_string,test_string.length,0);
    System.out.format("%d\n",LongToInt(test_crc32_hb));
     }
}
```

Result

```
$javac CRC32.java
$java -Xmx128M -Xms16M CRC32
Hello World
1243066710
951982353
```

Why am I getting different results? Am I missing something in conversion e.g. long to int or shift operator is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Java `int` is 32 bits; you should use that for all CRC calculations, then *finally* expand to `long` and mask 32 lower bits... or just return `int` and remember that it is to be considered unsigned.

Comment: (In 1.8+ use [toUnsignedLong](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toUnsignedLong-int-)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thanks. I am trying this on Java but will eventually port this code to Android.

Comment: regarding: `uint32_t previousCrc32 = 0)`  it is not valid C code to assign a value to a parameter in the formal parameter list.  (it is ok in C++ but this is tagged as C

Comment: @user3629249 yeah you are correct but I always compile with g++ even if it is c code. Hence, I overlooked it. :-)

Comment: regarding: `crc ^= *current++;`  this expression: `*current++;` will increment the pointer `current` then dereferencing the pointer to obtain the byte  I.E. the first byte in the data was being missed and maybe accessing the first byte after then end of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem - It was type casting issue. I changed the following

```
   crc = (Crc32Lookup16[LongToInt(temp1)] ^ (crc >>> 4));
   //...
   crc = (Crc32Lookup16[LongToInt(temp2)] ^ (crc >>> 4));
```

To

```
   crc = (Crc32Lookup16[LongToInt(temp1)] ^ ((int)crc >>> 4));
   //...
   crc = (Crc32Lookup16[LongToInt(temp2)] ^ ((int)crc >>> 4));
```